# PHP Script is only outputting 1 entry and should be 3 | WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, wordpress

I am using the following script to output 3 entries onto my WordPress page.

**However, for some reason it only outputs the first entry from that list. I moved the numbers around in the array, and it still only outputs 1 `<div>`.**
Despite there definitely being posts with the ID, 1, 4 & 31.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
        <?php $thePostIdArray = array("1","4","31"); ?>
        <?php $limit = 3; ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++; ?>
                <?php if ( $counter < $limit + 1 ): ?>
                    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <?php $post_id = $thePostIdArray[$counter-1]; ?>
                    <?php $queried_post = get_post($post_id); ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: That's allota help ;-) `<?php` tags aside, any ideas what may be the issue here?

Comment: Couldn't you use `query_posts( 'p=' . implode(',',$thePostIdArray) );`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php 
$thePostIdArray = array(1, 4, 31);
$limit = 3; 
$counter = 0;

foreach( $thePostIdArray as $post_id ){
        $counter++;

        if ( $counter > $limit )
            break;

        $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
        echo '<div class="post" id="post-'.$post_id.'">
                <h2>'.$queried_post->post_title.'</h2>
              </div>';    

} // endforeach
?>
```

Comment: Frederick, you are something of a legend. That worked beautifully!!! Just waiting for the 4 minutes to elapse and I'll green tick you. Many, many thanks!!

Comment: Whilst that code will certainly work it's a bit overkill for something that can be achieved using the wordpress API.  I might be missing something of course but if there's no particular reason for using counters and 'get_post' then the solution I post below might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason why you're using counters and get_post?  If not it would be far simpler to do the following:

```
<?php 
$post_ids = array(1, 4, 31);

//Use post__in to grab the posts that you're interested in (stored in the variable above) and posts_per_page to specify that you want to show all posts.  You can use other parameters for ordering etc if you want

query_posts(array('post__in' => $post_ids 'posts_per_page' => -1)); 

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title();?>
    //Use regular wordpress template tags here - no real need to use get_post

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`have_posts()` is part of "the loop" as Wordpress so affectionately calls it.  Your code does not modify this loop.  Have posts defaults to setting up post data based off the page you are viewing.  For something statically coded, try this:

```
<?php $PostIdArray = array(1, 4, 31);
foreach($PostIdArray as $ID) {
    $my_post = get_posts($ID); ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php echo $ID; ?>">
    <h2><?php echo $my_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```